# Iptables: allow specific ips on specific port

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables

I am trying to allow a few IPs on port 80 and disallow all other from access port 80.

Can someone suggest the iptables rules needed for this to occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -s FROMIP.1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -s FROMIP.2 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -s FROMIP.3 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
/sbin/iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j DROP
```

Notes:

- This assumes you are using a script which calls IPTABLES.  (If you are using /etc/sysconfig/iptables, drop the first /sbin/iptables command)
- This assumes IPTables is running on the webserver.  If its running on a firewall, replace the INPUT with FORWARD  (and optionally add -d DEST.IP after
  FROM.IPX if you want to block it to a single host
- This only deals with traffic on Port 80, I assume you wanted it.
- the -A is important, as it appends rules (matching order is important).  If you use -I to insert rules, reverse the order of the rules.

Comment: Do I have to flush existing rules? I am not quite sure if order matter in this case.

Comment: The answer is very much "it depends" entirely on your setup.  If you can provide more details on your current rules, how they are loaded and edited I can give you an answer.  In general terms, if you put those rules in IN REVERSE ORDER and with the -I flag rather then -A flag they will be inserted into the beginning of the table and will be effective even if you don't reload (until they are wiped at the next reboot)

Comment: You must make sure that the rules appear "soon enough". The `iptables` rules are executed in order, if some other rule does an ACCEPT, your rules won't be considered. This [tutorial](http://www.frozentux.net/documents/iptables-tutorial) might help, also look at the documentation for the tools your distribution favors.